# Regarding running a script from another

Tags: python, pygtk

Is there a way that I can run a script from another while getting output as readily as I get by executing it by itself.
For example:
I use the os.popen3 command to execute abc.py, but I am unable to get output from abc.py as readily as I would with doing `python abc.py`; it seems that I need to wait for os.popen3 command to finish:

```
fin, fout, ferr=os.popen3("abc.py")
out = fout.read()
err = ferr.read()
fo.write(out)
fe.write(err)
print out
print err
```

[EDIT]:fo and fe here are file handles to the output and error logs, respectively.

Also, what widget do I use to populate the output in, in pygtk?

Comment: What are `fo` and `fe` in your code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The subprocess module is the option, but the tricky part is to follow the output un parallel with your main loop of gtk, to accomplish that goal you must have to consider the platform that you are dealing, if you are in linux you can easily run another thread and use `gtk.gdk.threads_init` to use threads in pygtk, but if you are planing to run your application on windows, then you should use **generators** and **gobject.idle_add**.

About the widget, use `gtk.TextBuffer` associated with a `gtk.TextView`

Here is an example with threads

```
import gtk
import subprocess
import threading

gtk.gdk.threads_init()

class FollowProcess(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self, cmd, text_buffer):
        self.tb = text_buffer
        self.child = subprocess.Popen(cmd, shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
        super(FollowProcess, self).__init__()

    def run(self):
        while not self.child.poll():
            out = self.child.stdout.read(1)
            if out != '':
                gtk.gdk.threads_enter()
                self.tb.insert_at_cursor(out)
                gtk.gdk.threads_leave()

def destroy(w, cmd):
    cmd.child.terminate()
    gtk.main_quit()

i = 0
def click_count(btn):
    global i
    message.set_text('Calling button %d' %i)
    i += 1

other_command = 'python extranger.py'

w = gtk.Window()
w.resize(400, 400)

message = gtk.Label('Nothing')
tb = gtk.TextBuffer()
tv = gtk.TextView(tb)
scroll = gtk.ScrolledWindow()
scroll.set_policy(gtk.POLICY_AUTOMATIC, gtk.POLICY_AUTOMATIC)
scroll.add(tv)

box = gtk.VBox()
button = gtk.Button('Active button')

cmd = FollowProcess('python extranger.py', tb)

button.connect('clicked', click_count )

w.connect('destroy', destroy, cmd)
box.pack_start(button, False)
box.pack_start(message, False)
box.pack_start(scroll)


w.add(box)
w.show_all()
cmd.start()
gtk.main()
```

And in `extranger.py`

```
import time
import sys

i = 0
while True:
    print 'some output %d' % i
    sys.stdout.flush() # you need this to see the output
    time.sleep(.5)
    i += 1
```

Note how the button stills responsive even with the update in parallel.

Answer (score 2):

```
import subprocess
pro = subprocess.Popen('abc.py')
```

Is a much better way of fiddling with another scripts ins, outs, and errors.

Comment: But does it channel output from abc.py without making the the parent script to wait?

Comment: Could you be a little more elaborate, please.

Comment: The subprocess module allows you to spawn new processes, connect to their input/output/error pipes, and obtain their return codes. This module intends to replace several other, older modules and functions.

Answer (score 0):

You mentioned *PyGtk* but you can give a try to *PyQt* and particularly *QProcess* class wich has some nice signals like :

- readyReadStandardError
- readyReadStandardOutput

Look for a similar tool with PyGtk.